# Checking whether a string contains some characters in python

Tags: python

I want to check if a string only contains A-Z and a-z and 0-9 and underscore and dash (_ -)

Any other special signs like !"#\% should not be contained

How can I write the regular expression?

and use `match` or ?

My strings look like these: QOIWU_W  QWLJ2-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `re.match` seems like a good match (pardon the pun). As for the regular expression, how about something like this: `'[A-Za-z0-9-_]*'`?

Comment: You can also use [\w-] instead of [A-Za-z0-9-_]

Answer (score 9):

Using `re` doesn't harm in any way, but just for scientific curiosity, another approach that doesn't require you to pass through `re` is using sets:

```
>>> valid = set('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_ ')
>>> def test(s):
...    return set(s).issubset(valid)
... 
>>> test('ThiS iS 4n example_sentence that should-pass')
True
>>> test('ThiS iS 4n example_sentence that should fail!!')
False
```

For conciseness, the testing function could also be written:

```
>>> def test(s):
...    return set(s) <= valid
```

**EDIT:** A bit of timing for the sake of curiosity (times are in seconds, for each test implementation it runs three sets of iterations):

```
>>> T(lambda : re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$', s)).repeat()
[1.8856699466705322, 1.8666279315948486, 1.8670001029968262]
>>> T(lambda : set(y) <= valid).repeat()
[3.595816135406494, 3.568570852279663, 3.564558982849121]
>>> T(lambda : all([c in valid for c in y])).repeat()
[6.224508047103882, 6.2116711139678955, 6.209425926208496]
```

Comment: You don't need the `list` calls to get the sets of characters.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber - Thank you, fixed (and it took off 1 sec from the timings...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression module.

```
import re
if (re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$',testString)):
    //successful match
```

Comment: What kind of Python has that syntax?

Comment: @Oliver thank you, but I guess, ^ and $ are required in PHP, not in python.

Comment: @manxing Not so. ^ and $ mark the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

No need to go regexp.

```
import string

# build a string containing all valid characters
match=string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_' + '-' + ' '

In [25]: match
Out[25]: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_- '

test='QOIWU_W QWLJ2-'

In [22]: all([c in match for c in test])
Out[22]: True

In [23]: test2='abc ;'

In [24]: all([c in match for c in test2])
Out[24]: False
```

Comment: time for `in` is linear with the length of the search string so it wasn't a major surprise. Thanks for the benchmark though!

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
re.search('[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]+', your_string) == None
```

re.search() will return a match object if it comes across any instances of one or more non-alphanumeric characters and None otherwise. So you'd be checking if the string is safe.